# My admin panel seems to load bad

Tags: magento2, admin

I've just installed Magento on my localhost (XAMPP) server and I can't do anything with my panel.
I can only do click on "Dashboard" and "Find partners & extensions".

Also, I can't see any interface icons.

I let you here a screen of my interface.
I hope you can help me. Thanks beforehand.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: I already have both of them:

Comment: <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
                
<item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>

Comment: Do I just remove the Symlink path?

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: Ok I got it finally ^^. Thanks for your time.